# Search result website title for Bing and Yahoo

Tags: google, title, bing, yahoo

I own a website and in the Google Search result, everything is ok, the result have the right title (the `<title>` tag of my page).

On Bing & Yahoo, the title which is displayed on result is not the good one. I think it is an very old (more than 1 month).

There is a way to ask for an update or something?

**EDIT 1**:

After one month, there is no change. When i search my domain name, informations given are outdated, if i search the page title, the informations are corrects..

How can i change this ?

Answer (score 4):

I can't really speak for Yahoo but in case of Bing, submit request about "Outdated cache removal"

Read more about this here:

http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/bing-content-removal-tool-cb6c294d

Please note, that all search engines eventually crawl over your web pages again. It's just a matter of time.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, i didnt now about the outdated cache removal resquest possibility.

Answer (score 4):

Caching is done on the search engine's servers, so there isn't much you can do about it.
it is outside your direct control since you are at the mercy of specific search engines re-indexing you.

You can (and should) sign up for Bing and Google webmaster tools (Yahoo is part of Bing's tools). This will give you an opportunity to let them know you've updated and that you would like to be crawled. It will also give you a chance to know when they have crawled you and what errors they may have encountered (so that you can correct them).

To make yourself even more friendly for being crawled, you should have an **XML sitemap**. You can submit the location of your sitemap through those tool sites for indexing.

As the other answer mentioned,that all search engines eventually crawl over your web pages again. It's just a matter of time.

Comment: Hope this info will help u,i also faced same problem long back.u r question will help in feature...

Comment: Yes, i followed your advices, i hope it's will be resolved soon!

Answer (score 1):

Publish new content linking to your HP. This will force search engines to recrawl. I found this helps (at least it speeds up the process), above all if you add some new content to the HP too (search engines will eventually compare your website with the content cached and update).